# Trouble with a variable in Python (that makes no sense)

Tags: python, python-3.x, function, variables

So, I am writing this program that basically works like a scientific calculator and the code is such:

```
print('>>>initializing program...')

# -- VARIABLE TELLS THE PROGRAM WHAT MENU IT IS IN -- #
current_menu = 'mm'

# -- PRINT MAIN MENU ITEMS -- #
def print_main_menu():
    current_menu = 'mm'
    return('\n-MAIN MENU- \n1. Calculation \n2. Graph \n3. Solver')

# -- PRINT CALCULATION MENU ITEMS -- #
def print_calculation_menu():
    print('\n- Calculation Mode')
    current_menu = 'calc'
    print(current_menu) #------DEBUG PRINT 1------#
    return('Type your calculation below:')

# -- PRINT GRAPH MENU ITEMS -- #
def print_graph_menu():
    print('\n- Graph Mode')
    current_menu = 'graph'
    print(current_menu) #------DEBUG PRINT 2------#
    return('Write graph equation below:')

def print_solver_menu():
    print('\n- Solver Mode')
    current_menu = 'solver'
    print(current_menu) #------DEBUG PRINT 3------#
    return('Write your equation below:')

# -- ANALYZE USER INPUT -- #
def take_input(userinput):
    if userinput == 'home':
        print_main_menu()
    elif userinput == 'quit':
        print('\n >>>Terminating program...')
        quit()
    else:
        if current_menu == 'mm':
            if userinput == '1':
                print(print_calculation_menu())
                user_in = input()
                take_input(user_in)
            elif userinput == '2':
                print(print_graph_menu())
                user_in = input()
                take_input(user_in)
            elif userinput == '3':
                print(print_solver_menu())
                user_in = input()
                take_input(user_in)
            else:
                print(current_menu) #------DEBUG PRINT 4------#
                print('\nUndefined mode selected. Returning to Main Menu')
                print_main_menu()
                user_in = input()
                take_input(user_in)
        elif current_menu == 'calc':
            user_in = input()
            print('\n' + calcmenu_calculate(user_in))
            #--MARKER--#
            user_in = input()
            take_input(user_in)
        elif current_menu == 'graph':
            user_in = input()
            print('\n' + graphmenu_graph(user_in))
            #--MARKER--#
            user_in = input()
            take_input(user_in)
        elif current_menu == 'solver':
            user_in = input()
            print('\n' + solvermenu_solve(user_in))
            #--MARKER--#
            user_in = input()
            take_input(user_in)
        else:
            print('An unknown error has occured, and Maryam had to terminate. Sorry for the inconvenience')
            print('\n >>>Terminating program...')
            quit()
            
            
print('\nWelcome')

# -- LOOP TERMINATES WHEN USER ENTERS QUIT COMMAND -- #
while True:
    current_menu = 'mm'
    print(print_main_menu())
    user_in = input()
    take_input(user_in)
```

the `take_input` function analyzes input. It can understand which menu the user is currently in via the value of `current_menu` (which is set to "mm" by default, standing for main menu), and then analyze the input according to what is fitting. When I run the program, though, things get weird. The main menu loads up fine and I can select the different modes, which executes the functions for those said modes and prints out the according instructions to the user; but when I try to actually do something the program seems to be stuck in processing inputs as if it is in the main menu. When the functions run, the sections marked as `DEBUG PRINT 1-3` display that the `current_mode` variable has been in fact changed to the respective value, but when I try to input something, the program spits out "Undefined mode selected. Returning to Main Menu" which should be the case if someone was in the main menu and entered an input other than 1, 2 or 3. `DEBUG PRINT 4` also shows that the `current_menu` variable seems to be still set to "mm" even though it was supposedly changed by the functions `print_calculation_menu()`, `print_graph_menu()` and `print_solver_menu()`.

What I want the code to do is to change the `current_menu` variable whenever the user goes into a menu, and I want the `take_input()` function to be able to identify which menu the user is in based on the value of said variable and process their input accordingly.

I tried to solve the problem by moving the lines of code that changed the value of `current_menu` to the places marked as `#--MARKER--#`, but that somehow made it worse, making the program output this error: `UnboundLocalError: local variable 'current_menu' referenced before assignment`.

I seriously have no idea what to do here.

Comment: What editor are you using?

Comment: You are using a global variable current_menu. This usually works fine however I find that sometimes you end up having to declare the variable as global everywhere you use it. You could try a calculator Class and have the menu as a property of the class.

Comment: I'm using VS Code but running the code in terminal via the python3 command

Comment: @jwal it's not that "sometimes you end up having to declare the variable as global". There is a definite rule - see the answer below

Comment: @gimix the definite rule seems to ignore the fact that ```somevar = 5\ndef here():\n
    print(somevar)\nhere()\n``` prints 5. ETA ... you didn't fully read the answer below :(.

Comment: I wrote that answer :D

Answer (score 1):

You need to check the [docs](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/simple_stmts.html?highlight=global#grammar-token-python-grammar-global_stmt): *It would be impossible to assign to a global variable without global, although free variables may refer to globals without being declared global*

In other words you can *access* a global variable, but you cannot *assign* to it if you don't declare it as `global`. Without that declaration, each of your `current_menu = ...` statements are shadowing the global variable, and creating a local one of the same name, that will disappear as soon as the function returns.

I think this behaviour was a good design decision: while using globals is generally not a good idea, modifying a global in a function is definitely a bad practice 99% of the time. So as long as you only use the value Python doesn't request anything; but if you want to set a new value, then you have to explicitly tell that you want to do so.